# is it ok to fetch data in each screen mounting(navigating) React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

Consider an entity: `Product`, i have a page that shows `Products` to user.

in the page showing `Products` in `componentDidMount` i make API reuqest and fetch the data. now with having just a global object named `GlobalState` or `Redux store` i save the fetched data in my global state.

then in my page i use global state(as mentioned before either `Redux store` or just a `global object`) to show the data. until now this is my approach.

the question is here: each time i navigate to the page `componentDidMount` gets called and make the api request and populate the global state again. is this ok? if so whats the point of saving them in a global state.
i think im doing sth useless again and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Amas, your right, bcoz **componentDidMount** component, run each time (ie), when navigating into that screen. if you need to update the global variable value or state it's approach is okay, unless no need.

also try to change the API Request call from `componentDidMount`. its affecting you application running very slow. suggestion create new function paste the API Request here...

Ex:

```
ComponentDidMount(){ 
   this.apiReq();
} 


apiReq(){
    request code here....
 }
```